# Trouble displaying % symbol on Android when sharing from RN app

Tags: android, react-native, unicode

My React Native app lets people share discounts with their friends by the message. The message is hardcoded in the app:

```
const message = 'Get 10% off!'
Linking.openURL(`sms:? &body=${message}`)
```

On Android, the % sign is not interpreted correctly and looks like this:

`% o` is transformed into this weird question mark.
[image]

I tried replacing `%` with various Unicode, escaping it `\%%`, or setting it to upper case, nothing worked.

**How should I encode % so it renders as expected on Android?**

Answer (score 1):

Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for every parameter you want to send through the link, to properly encode any special characters.

```js
const message = encodeURIComponent('Get 10% off!')
Linking.openURL(`sms:? &body=${message}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try HTML code for the symbol %:

```
<Text>
    &#10140;
<Text>
```

This should work, but be careful:

```
<Text>
    {'&#10140;'}
<Text>
```

That will not work